# CSS class as condition in if statement

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

Is it possible to use a css class as a condition in an if statement?

For example:

```
if (.css-class) {/*fire this code*/}
```

Comment: you have to check the `classList` property of the DOM element to see if the class you depend your condition upon exists or not.

Comment: Here is a general tip: Don't write apologetic introductory paragraphs. Firstly, there are far too many active users and new questions at any given moment. *Nobody* has read your other questions and therefore nobody has the context you are trying to establish. Secondly, think how your question looks like in a year, or in a Google result. Nobody cares that it's your, like, second noobish question. In the future, just get right to the point.

Comment: What do you intend for that to mean?

Comment: Nor do you need to write "Thanks", "or "Thanks in advance". If someone writes an answer that solves your problem, or that you think is useful, you thank them then by upvoting or accepting their answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by using `classList.contains` from the `classList API`:

```
if (element.classList.contains(myClass)) {

[... JAVASCRIPT HERE ...]

}
```

Other methods of `classList` (apart from `classList.contains`) are:

- `element.classList.add()` *(adds a class to the element)*
- `element.classList.remove()` *(removes a class from the element)*
- `element.classList.toggle()` *(removes the class if it is present or adds the class if it is absent)*
- `element.classList.item()` *(returns the index of the class in the element's list of classes)*

---

**Further Reading:**

`Element.classList` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList